# Which approach to use for Spatial Autocorrelation, Moran's I?

Tags: r, autocorrelation, spatial

I am working out with some spatial data from Yelp dataset. I'd like to take a single city, plot all the restaurants and then check wheter there's some clustering that affects the grade that people give to a restaurant, i.e. people tend to value worse those restaurant in poor neighbourhoods.

However, at this point I am stucked as I don't know which steps to follow. I have been reading literature and Blogs but I haven't managed to figure out how to tackle the issue.

If you could just give me some ideas or basic points of how to solve it i'd really appreciate!!

Thank you very much!

Comment: Comparing evaluations to neighborhood quality appears to be a form of *regression* model, not a clustering calculation.  This makes one wonder what you are really trying to accomplish.  Could you clarify?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to know if there is some kind of clustering by zones in the marks that people give to Yelp restaurants. To do so I have GPS coordinates of each restaurant and the mark they have been given by Yelp users. As far as I know spatial autocorrelation seems to be the best tool to asses this dataset, however, there might be other regressions or tools I am not aware of. 

Thank you!

Comment: Of course there will be spatial clustering, because restaurant locations will be clustered regardless of any reviews or ratings. This suggests that measures of spatial correlation by themselves will be useless or misleading. Because clustering is not the same thing as, nor even evidence of, a relationship with other neighborhood characteristics, it's unclear what you're trying to accomplish.